# 'Delete' quad in openGL

Tags: opengl

im creating a game, my character shoots a bullet, and is going to collide with an enemy, which is drawn like this in display();

```
glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(260, -180, 0.0);
        e[0] = new Platform(0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 0, textures[17], 260, -180);
    glPopMatrix();
```

How do i go about deleting/not drawing the object once the bullet has collided with it? Im not after code just an idea of how to go about it, thanks!

Comment: You're thinking in terms of a scene graph, again. I already told you in detail, that OpenGL doesn't work that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264682/position-moving-2d-object-opengl/5266358#5266358

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( bullet hits character ){
    listOfCharacters.remove(character)
)
```

and later :

```
function drawAllCharacters :
    for each Character in listOfCharacters :
        draw Character
```

(not sure it's this kind of stuff you want)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any draw code there, but the general principle is to conditionally skip the drawing.  If you're drawing the quads en masse rather than individually, it may take some work to do that.  For example switching from `glDrawArrays` to `glDrawElements` allows you to draw only a subset of the quads you've defined.